# What is used to detect light from fiber optic signals in high speed Internet?

Tags: photodiode, phototransistor, light-sensor, optical-fibre

I'm curious, do they use photodiodes or something? As far as I know, that would be the cheapest way to do high speed communications over fiber (fibre? I'm 'murican) but I'm not sure.

Comment: For *any* high speed optical communications (the internet just happens to have some high speed nodes), PIN diodes are commonly used in the receiver.

Comment: In the past when PIN diodes were not as well developed use was made of avalanche photo diodes to gain fast responses.

Comment: While fiber-optic communication is on-topic here, it's even more on-topic when [tagged with "fiber" at the Network Engineering StackExchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiber).

Comment: @davidcary I didn't even know there was a Network Engineering area. Thanks, will keep in mind if I ever have a similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, high speed photodiodes are the simplest way to do this. A receiver will usually consist of a photodiode and transimpedance amplifier (current in, voltage out). After that, it's just a high speed serial electrical signal, and that gets fed into clock data recovery circuitry, deserializers, etc.

There can be components in front of the photodiode, though. Wavelength division multiplexing is used to send multiple signals over one fiber. 40G and 100G Ethernet uses 4 parallel data streams, and you can get WDM modules that include the optical filters necessary to combine and split as needed. In this case, the receiver would consist of a WDM demultiplexer and four photodiodes and TIAs.

For coherent transmission, an interferometer is used to split the light out into in-phase and quadrature components, which are sent to two separate photodiodes and TIAs, followed by very high speed ADCs and a pile of digital signal processing.